# how I will get all the record from QA to a fresh sandbox?

Tags: data-loader, data

I want to get all the records in a fresh sandbox from QA. please guide me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some tools like Dataloader or workbench to export the records from QA sandbox and import them in Fresh sandbox which you wish to .

You can also clone the new sandbox from QA as well.

You can also try using salesforce CLI commands as listed in the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Go for a creation of Full Copy Sandbox cloning your QA Sandbox. You'll get all the data in your fresh sandbox.

Note: Full Copy Sandbox is the key.